# How to disable Quarkus logging to a file (quarkus.log)?

Tags: quarkus

I would like to run my Quarkus app in a container where the best practice is to only log to the console and not to a file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable logging, edit your `application.properties` file and add the following property:

```
quarkus.log.file.enable=false
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Quarkus logs to both the console and to a file named `quarkus.log`.

In cases where writing to the log file is not necessary (for example when running a Quarkus app in a Kubernetes Pod), `quarkus.log.file.enable=false` can be used.

This property can be set either in `application.properties` or be overridden at runtime (using `-Dquarkus.log.file.enable=false`).

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging-guide) guide for more information about logging.

**UPDATE**

With [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1603) PR, logging to a file is now disabled by default.